# check if current time is between two given times period?

Tags: php

I am new to php and finding its date time manual a little bit tricky.

I want to check if the current time `date('h:i a', time());` is between two given time interval `$startTime` and `$endTime`.

where `$startTime = "5:00AM"`  and `$endTime = "8:00AM".`

I have seen similar question with logic like `(($currentTime >= $startTime) && ($currentTime <= $endTime) )` but nothing is working. I guess I am missing something very basic here.

Please help.

This is what I tried

```
var_dump($startTime);  string(6) "8:00AM" 
var_dump($endTime);   string(6) "5:00PM"
$startTime = new DateTime($startTime); 
$endTime = new DateTime($endTime); 
$now = new DateTime(); 

if ($now >= $startTime && $now < $endTime) {
   pr('Time now is between start and end time'); 
}

but It is not working
```

Comment: That's because those existing answers use timestamp values for the comparison, not formatted strings containing human readable times

Comment: is there any way I can convert these strings to timestamps

Comment: you may want to review this http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php and http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: `$startTime = new DateTime($startTime);
$endTime = new DateTime($endTime);` and then you can compare using `$now = new DateTime();
if ($now >= $startTime && $now < $endTime) {
    echo 'Time now is between start and end time';
}`

Comment: Change all the time into timestamp and then compare it

Comment: @MarkBaker I tried your suggestion and edited the question in your method but it is not working.

Comment: @User101 - [It works perfectly correctly, see for yourself](https://3v4l.org/ihJYS).... what time is it now where you are?

Comment: Its works without any changes : https://eval.in/919768

Comment: yeah it worked thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this code

convert time into `strtotime()` and than `compare two time` its work

```
<?php
$currentTime =date('h:i A', time());
$startTime = "5:00 AM";
$endTime = "8:00 AM";

if((strtotime($currentTime) >= strtotime($startTime)) && (strtotime($currentTime) <= strtotime($endTime)) ){
   echo $currentTime;
}

?>
```

Comment: @User101 Is your _current time_ between those two times **right now**? If not then it _isn't_ going to work...

Comment: check your current time to print current time.

Comment: @Bhargav I imagine the code you posted was run on a server and it didn't work because OP's current time is not between 5AM and 8AM

Comment: yes because your current time not between start and end time